# AWS Serverless custom authorizer on unauthorized - returns 401 on local but always 500 after deployment

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, authorization, serverless

Im using custom authorizers for verify user token.
On checking the function local using postman - it works as excepted - returns 401 unauthorized.
After serverless deploy - while unverified token - it always returns 500 internal server error.

I understood that using AuthorizationToken instead of Authorization will execute 401 after deploy. The thing is it will be missing here:

```
      let token: string = event.authorizationToken;
```

Here is my code:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) : Promise<any> =>  {
    try {
      //check if there is a token
      let token: string = event.authorizationToken;
      if (!token) {
          callback(new HttpError(401,'Unauthorized'), null);
      }
      //clean the the bearer
      if (token.includes('Bearer ')) {
          token = token.substring(7, token.length);
      }
      //check if it is a valid token
      const cognitoUserId = await verifyUserToken(token)
      if (!cognitoUserId) {
          callback(new HttpError(401,'Unauthorized'), null);
      }
      callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn, cognitoUserId));
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error authorizing user', e);
        callback(e, null);
    }
}
```

on Yaml file:

```
shareImage:
    handler: src/app/handlers/shareImageHandler.handler
    vpc: ${self:custom.vpc.private}
    events:
      - http:
          path: /shareImage
          method: post
          authorizer:
            name: authorizerFunc
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
```

Comment: i suspect this is ebcause you are returning an exception (httpError) - any exception from the lambda causes a 500 error from API gateway.

instead you can try returning a json with 'statusCode'  of the error you want. Its been a bit, but im pretty sure you then also have to set up a MethodResponse  Transformation to handle this and return anything other than a 500 (default api gateway only returns 200, 500, and 400 (if IAM permissions deny access)